# Highlight inputs that have the same non-empty value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want is to check if the textboxes has the same value. If they have the same value then highlight them, except for textboxes that have no value.

Here's a sample fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qjqa1et2/61/

Here's my current jQuery code:

```
var inputs = $('input');

inputs.filter(function(i,el){
return inputs.not(this).filter(function() {
    return this.value === el.value;
}).length !== 0;
}).addClass('red');
```

The problem is that the textboxes that have no values are still highlighted.

Comment: `return this.value && this.value === el.value;`

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks.. you are a great help... =)

Comment: IMHO a better solution would be `return this.value && inputs.not(this).filter(function() {` http://jsfiddle.net/f4582bz5/

Answer (score 0):

you could do this:

```
    return inputs.not(this).filter(function() {
        return (this.value && (this.value === el.value));
    }).length !== 0;
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/maverickosama92/qjqa1et2/62/

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the element is non-empty with `!el.value` (equivalent to `el.value == ''` in this case). If so, we can immediately exclude it (without checking other elements) by returning `false`.

```
var inputs = $('input');

inputs.filter(function(i,el){
    if (!el.value) return false; // <= new line
    return inputs.not(this).filter(function() {
        return this.value === el.value;
    }).length !== 0;
}).addClass('red');
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ges4vwfb/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputs = $('input'); 

inputs.filter(function(i,el) {
    if(el.value!="") {
        return inputs.not(this).filter(function() { 
            return this.value === el.value;
        }).length !== 0;
     } 
}).addClass('red');
```

---

Comment: While answering add some details also.. code explanation is required to understand others...